# jQuery UI Accordion, default expanded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the jQueryUI Accordion plugin for site navigation. My page is rendered server-side, the current tab gets an attribute `defaultactive=true`. The markup is as following:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>One</li>
    <li defaultactive="true">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I know this snippet to work as expected:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ active: 2 });
```

What do I have to write to get the exact position (zero-based) of the li-element with `defaultactive-attribute` within the `ul` container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `index()` to achieve this:

```
$('.accordion li[defaultactive="true"]').index()
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dm74e/)

Comment: thank you, didn't knew that it is still a reference to the collection

Comment: Hi, need your help here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327296/2333214 if you have a minute to spare...

Answer (score 4):

Since all your `<li>` elements are siblings, you can use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    active: $(".accordion li[defaultactive=true]").index()
});
```

Note that according to your markup, you should use a class selector (`.accordion`), not an id selector (`#accordion`).

Comment: Hi need your help here on accordion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327296/2333214 if you have a minute to spare